# Show $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that the function $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. I have no idea how to do this. I think it's pretty obvious that the function converges since $2^{n}$ increases really quickly. I tried doing something with analyticity which implies infinitely differentiable; however, I got nowhere.

Comment: This series is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$, and the series of the derivatives converges uniformly on $\Bbb R$. This is enough to conclude that the derivative of $f(x)$ is simply the series of the derivatives.

Comment: how do we know the series is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Do you know Weierstrass' M-test? It's so simple to use here.

Comment: i am allowed to use weierstrass m test, yes

Answer (score 0):

Write $\sin(nx)={1\over 2i}\bigl(e^{inx}-e^{-inx}\bigr)$, so that your $f$ appears as $$f(x)={1\over 2i}\left(\sum_{n\geq1} p^n-\sum_{n\geq1} q^n\right)\ .$$
Simplifying in the end will give you a simple expression for $f$, namely
$$f(x)={2\sin x\over5-4\cos x}\ .$$